# mount google cloud storage bucket but cache locally

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I would like to know if there is a way to mount google cloud storage bucket as a folder for the first time 
and each time we read the file, cache it locally (so it won't use money/bandwidth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCSFUSE has two type of caching available, Stat caching and type caching. You can refer to [this document](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/blob/6ee9f0f920cd17545c483f5425fd6c472feb3deb/docs/semantics.md#implicit-directories) which provide detailed information on these types of caching with there trade-offs.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, though. gcsfuse does data caching only between `open()` and `close()` -- the cached (gcsfuse calls it "staged") file is removed after upload.

An alternative would be `s3fs` which has a cache feature and can be told to connect to GCS (using S3 semantics).